# Unable to access site on aws ecs

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I tried to deploy my flask app and followed these two guides [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-a-flask-api-on-aws-ecs-part-3-c1ca552e65d), [2](https://faun.pub/deploying-your-first-docker-container-on-aws-ecs-ed19a3599b6c). But I can't connect to the site by task public IP.
here my dokerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
# By default, listen on port 5000
EXPOSE 80

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY  . .


# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD python app.py
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you run the same Docker image locally, does it work? Can you connect when it is running locally?

Comment: @Mark B it's working on local host when i run image via docker compose.

Comment: Did you check the logs in CloudWatch Logs? Did you verify the security group settings? That tutorial mentions using a load balancer, so you should probably be trying to access the site via the load balancer's URL, not the task IP.

Comment: If it is working locally then the issue seems to be going from networking end. If you are using EC2 launch type, check if the EC2 instance has the public IP or not. If not, you need to fix that and can you share which HTTP code you are receiving ?

Comment: I receive this when using public IP in the browser. Unable to access site Site x.xxx.xxx.xxxx cannot connect.
Try doing the following:

Use your Internet connection.
Requires proxy and firewall settings.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I don't use a load balancer, just try to connect by public IP. I use Fargate.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling public IP is not enough, you also have to attach the service you create with a security group that enables http requests on a given port from a given source.

If you go to your cluster and click on "Deploy" to deploy a new service, you will see one of the tabs is Networking. Create a security group that allows HTTP requests from anywhere on port 80 as shown in the picture.

Security group configuration:

[image: Security group configuration]